# fixing the greater and less than signs in my math game in livecode

Tags: math, operator-keyword, livecode

I am using two variables with random numbers from 1-10 in each and I want the user to click on the <= or >=  symbol pictures that I used a toolTip  in them . All the code is written in the card's script and the  methods are called in the needed button or field . I included a picture of my app's interface too . Thank you [image]

here is my code
can someone please help and spot what's wrong ? Thank you

```
 local _leftNumberValue 
local _rightNumberValue
local _correctAnswer
local _userAnswerValue
local _userScore
local _numberOfQuestions
on openCard
   PreparingQuestion
end openCard

on PreparingQuestion
   put random(10) into _leftNumberValue 
   put _leftNumberValue  into field "leftNumber"
   put random  (10)  into _rightNumberValue
   put _rightNumberValue  into field "rightNumber" 
   if  _leftNumberValue >=  _rightNumberValue
   then
      put _leftNumberValue  into _correctAnswer
      add 1 to _numberOfQuestions
      put _numberOfQuestions into field "numberOfQuestions"
   end if 
end PreparingQuestion

on CheckUsersAnswer
   put field "userAnswer" into _userAnswerValue
   if _userAnswerValue = _correctAnswer
   then
      if _userScore < 4
      then  
         AddPointsToPlayer
         PreparingQuestion
      else 
         answer "Great Job :) You can move on  to the next level"
      end if 
   end if 
   put empty into field "userAnswer"
end CheckUsersAnswer

on AddPointsToPlayer
   add 1 to _userScore
   put _userScore into field "scoreBoard"
end AddPointsToPlayer

on StartOver 
   put empty into field "numberOfQuestions"
   put 0 into _userScore
   put 0 into _numberOfQuestions
   put _numberOfQuestions into field "numberOfQuestions"
   put _userScore into field  "scoreBoard"
end StartOver
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell us what happens and what is supposed to happen?

Comment: What should happen is that the program will choose random numbers from 1-10 and show them in the fields as shown in the picture attached above ,

Comment: the player will practice the greater and less than math problem and click on the symbol picture that he/she thinks is true , when clicked on the picture symbol > or < it will appear in the square field between the numbers because I wrote it in the toolTip inspector in each picture symbol < and > , my problem is that when I test/run the program it doesn't work because I can't see that I've got a point in the score field , I don't know what's the problem so I need your help .

Comment: To answer what is supposed to happen if the answer is wrong? well nothing yet , I will just add and answer command that will tell the player to try again (answer "Try again")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to explain the play and point of the game.
I tried recreating your stack as best I could from the description and code, it seems to work OK, but I'm not sure I fully understand exactly what should be happening or where it's going wrong.

One point; your CheckUsersAnswer handler only checks for a correct answer, what is supposed to happen if the answer is wrong?

Update:

Revised handlers…

```lc
on PreparingQuestion
   put random(10) into _leftNumberValue 
   put _leftNumberValue  into field "leftNumber"
   put random  (10)  into _rightNumberValue
   put _rightNumberValue  into field "rightNumber" 
   
   ## CHANGED: Determine the correct answer…
   if _leftNumberValue > _rightNumberValue then put ">" into _correctAnswer
   if _leftNumberValue < _rightNumberValue then put "<" into _correctAnswer
   if _leftNumberValue = _rightNumberValue then put "=" into _correctAnswer
   
   add 1 to _numberOfQuestions
   put _numberOfQuestions into field "numberOfQuestions"
end PreparingQuestion

on CheckUsersAnswer
   put field "userAnswer" into _userAnswerValue
   if _userAnswerValue = _correctAnswer then
      if _userScore < 4 then  
         AddPointsToPlayer
         PreparingQuestion
      else 
         answer "Great Job :) You can move on  to the next level"
      end if
      
      ## ADDED: Message for user to try again…
   else
      answer "Wrong answer. Please try again."
   end if 
   put empty into field "userAnswer"
end CheckUsersAnswer
```

Comment: What should happen is that the  program will choose  random numbers  from 1-10 and show them in the fields as shown in the picture attached above ,

Comment: I changed two of your handlers slightly and as far as I can see it works as expected…
It is too long to post here, so I've edited the answer above.

Comment: Thank you Paul . Very very very much :)  . I put your code and it worked perfectly!!! I really appreciate taking your time to help me